# Ubuntu doesn't read some DVD discs

Tags: vlc, dvd

I have some DVD discs which are not read by Ubuntu (16.04). I have 16 DVD discs with TV series (4 seasons, every season has 4 DVDs), in every season there is one DVD disc containing 4 episodes and 3 discs with 3 episodes. I can watch movies from all the discs with 3 episodes but discs with 4 episodes don't work. I tried to run the discs in VLC - nothing happens while trying to open disc. I also tried to run it in Totem - then I get an error "cannot run a movie".

I have Windows 8 on this computer (with the same DVD drive) and I can play these DVDs in VLC on Windows, so these DVD discs are OK and it's not a hardware issue.

Comment: Did you install libdvdcss? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs

Comment: Yes, I have the latest version of libdvdcss.